# Coding for the first time (Java hangman game)- going from console-based to GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, stringbuffer

I am **completely new to programming** and I have to complete some tasks in Java (I'm using Eclipse). This one is a **hangman game**. My code is below. I have written a console-based program that basically works (counting lives instead of drawing a hangman graphic).

I think this question will seem very simple to most people, but I would really appreciate your help.

I am trying my best to look for answers online, but as a complete novice it is hard to know where to start. I would really just like to know if I am on the right track so that I don't waste too much time.

**I am supposed to (and want to!) do this myself, so ideally I would like hints on what to focus on.**

The questions I have are:

1. I now need to **create a GUI** (which I have never done before):
   *how useful is this code that I have already worked out? Is everything completely different once I start creating the game with a GUI?*
2. I used a `StringBuffer` to store the previously guessed letters. I
   wanted to **search** this in order to display the word with all the
   previously guessed letters filled in (as it stands it only prints
   out the current guess with all the other letters obscured). Is that
   possible?

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    String secretWord;
    int secretWordLength;
    int position;
    int livesLost = 0;
    int totalLives = 10;
    int lettersRemaining;
    boolean guessInWord;
    char guess;
    StringBuffer prevGuessedLetters;

    //prompt user to enter a word and set as an instance of the secretWord variable
    System.out.println("Enter a word:");
    secretWord = myScanner.next();

    //determine the length of the word entered
    secretWordLength = secretWord.length();
    System.out.println(secretWordLength);
    lettersRemaining = secretWordLength;

    for (position = 0; position < secretWordLength; position++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();

    //loop starts
    while (lettersRemaining > 0 && livesLost < 10) {
        //prompt user to guess a letter
        System.out.println("Guess a letter:");
        guess = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);

        //check if the letter guessed is in the secretWord  
        guessInWord = (secretWord.indexOf(guess)) != -1;

        if (guessInWord == false) {
            livesLost++;
            System.out.print("Sorry, you have lost a life. You still have ");
            System.out.print(totalLives -= livesLost);
            System.out.println(" life/lives left. Keep trying.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("That was a good guess, well done!");

            for (position = 0; position < secretWordLength; position++) {
                if (secretWord.charAt(position) == guess) {
                    System.out.print(guess);
                    lettersRemaining--;
                } else {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        prevGuessedLetters = buffer.append(guess);
        System.out.print("Previously guessed letters: ");
        System.out.println(prevGuessedLetters);
        System.out.print("Letters remaining: ");
        System.out.println(lettersRemaining);
    }

    if (livesLost == totalLives) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
    } else {
        System.out.print("Well done, you win! The word was ");
        System.out.println(secretWord);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java comes with a GUI toolkit called [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), which you should learn to use for the purposes of your task at hand.

As far as searching for previously guessed letters, you may be better served by the [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), which is a `Collection` of unique elements. You could use a `Set` of [`Character`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), i.e. a `Set<Character>`.

A crude example:

```
Set<Character> guesses = new HashSet<Character>();
Character guess;
// etc.

while (lettersRemaining > 0 && livesLost < 10)
{
    //prompt user to guess a letter
    System.out.println("Guess a letter:");
    guess = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);

    if (guesses.contains(guess)) {
        System.out.println("You have already guessed this character!");
    } else {
        guesses.add(guess);
        //check if the letter guessed is in the secretWord
        guessInWord = (secretWord.indexOf(guess))!= -1;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Actually, you can get some extra mileage out of the [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) method by taking advantage of the fact that it returns `true` if the element was not already in the set:

```
    if (guesses.add(guess)) {
        //check if the letter guessed is in the secretWord
        guessInWord = (secretWord.indexOf(guess))!= -1;
        // etc.
    } else {
        System.out.println("You have already guessed this character!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for your first question:

-Your code it's useful to your goal, so keep it up. Search about Swing library which it's a graphical lib for java, it will let you make a GUI without so much hard work.

About your second question:

-Right now i can't help you with it but it's not so hard so keep looking for it.

Comment: This would be better as a comment, since it does not address the entire issue the OP is having.

Answer (score 0):

1. By adding a GUI, your application will be longer and more structurally complex. It might not be a good idea to have all the code in 1 main method like your current program. So you might want to re-arrange your code into several different methods (also called procedures/sub-routines in other languages). This technique is call procedural programming which is intended to make your coding life easier.

   That being told, your code is not completely wasted when switching to GUI. The game logic remains the same. Nothing changes except the way the program interacts with users. This time, you receives guesses and outputs answers using Swing objects like [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) ([Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) is the default graphic library of Java. There's a lot out there but it's a good start). You'll also want to look at JPanel and JFrame (ways of telling the graphic window where exactly you want to put your stuff - so called layout).
2. StringBuffer is just a modifiable version of String. To perform searching/read through operations, try an array-like data structure. Here I use `ArrayList` which is the very basic data structure in Java:

   ```
    ArrayList<String> buffer;
    boolean addGuess(String inputString){ 
         boolean isNewGuess = true;
         for (String s: buffer){
             if (s.equals(inputString)){
             isNewGuess = false;
             break;
             } 
         } 
        if (isNewGuess) buffer.add(inputString);
        return isNewGuess;
    }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

### using Hang-Man Game simple logic

> optional this is package name
>
> ### package arr_game;

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HangMan {
public static char[] star;
    public static void main (String args[])
    {   
        char game[];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        String[] arr = { "pakistan", "india", "jarmany", "america", "rashia", "iran", "iraq", "japan", "sudan", "canada"};

        String word = arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)];
        int count = word.length();
        char[] CharArr=word.toCharArray(); 
        char[] star = word.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<star.length;i++)
        {
            star[i] = '*';
            System.out.print(star[i]);
        }

        for (int i=1; i<=3; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf ("\nGuess a Letter:");
            char letter= input.next().charAt(0);

            for (int j=0;j<CharArr.length; j++)
            {
                if(letter == star[j])
                {
                    System.out.println("this word already exist");
                }
                else
                {
                    if(letter==CharArr[j])
                    {
                        star[j]=letter;
                        i--;
                        System.out.printf("CORRECT GUESS!\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.print(star);
            switch(i+0)
            {
                    case 1: System.err.printf("Strike 1\n");
                        break;
                    case 2: System.err.printf("Strike 2\n");
                        break;
                    case 3: System.err.printf("Strike 3\n");
                        System.err.printf("You're out!!! The word is Not_Matched\n");
                        break;
            }   

            System.out.printf("\n");
            if((new String(word)).equals(new String(star))) 
            {
                System.err.printf("Winner Winner, Chicken Dinner!\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither does this answer OP's question, nor does it add any value after almost a year.